# too many dates on x-axis (matplotlib graph)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, matplotlib, graph

So, I have a dataset of stock prices, let's call it `sp.csv`.

[It has a date column that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1QCt.png)

[A price column that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R2oh.png)

Originally, my graph looked like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('sp.csv')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.plot(df['DATE'], df['PRC'])
```

[1st Graph looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOq8A.png)

I fixed the first graph's shape by converting the dates to a different format and adding a new column of it to the df, but now it has issues with the dates on the x-axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('sp.csv')

dates = df['DATE']
newdates = []

for i in dates:
    date = datetime.strptime(str(i), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m%d%Y')
    newdates.append(date)

df['DATE2'] = newdates

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.plot(df['DATE2'], df['PRC'])
```

[Graph now looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bhet.png)

I tried fixing it, but I'm not getting anywhere.
I tried adding locators and formatters, but then the years just disappear and start from the default 1970:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

[Graph then looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHZV1.png)

I don't really know what I'm doing, I just want the x-axis to display either the years or the years and months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert the date using `strptime()`, that will convert it to datetime. Do not use `strftime()`, which will convert it back to string. Check by using `df.info()` and make sure you see that the column you are plotting is datetime. Only then will you be able to use the dateformatters...

Below is the updated code. As I only had under 2 years AT&T data and my input date format was DD-MM-YYYY, this is the code and the graph I got. But, should work with years only as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('sp.csv')

dates = df['DATE']
newdates = []

for i in dates:
    date = datetime.strptime(str(i), '%d-%m-%Y')#.strftime('%m%d%Y')
    newdates.append(date)

df['DATE2'] = newdates

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.plot(df['DATE2'], df['PRC'])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know what the purpose of using `strftime` could be here?  `datetime.strptime(str(i), '%d-%m-%Y').strftime('%m%d%Y')` I saw someone using in it on another post on this forum when converting dates and plotting a graph with it, so that's why I initially went with it here, and didn't realise it was wrong until you pointed it out.

Comment: strftime converts datetime to string - opposite of what strptime does. There are some examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-strftime-function/) if you are interested...